# How to set cookie on DropWizard view and still return View?

Tags: java, cookies, response, dropwizard

I'm helping maintain an app where we use DropWizard, which is nice.

I'd like to set a cookie, and return the view still.

I see people mentioning this approach:

> Response r =
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok().cookie(COOKIE_HERE).entity(view).build();
>
> return r;

but to get that to work you have to return the "Response" object, and not the view.

Is there anyway to do this and be able to return a view instead of a response? I know I can use the HttpServletResponse to set the cookie, but I'd prefer to do it with the view or response object if possible to avoid extra context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this fits your requirements (with io.dropwizard 0.7.1):

```
@GET
@ExceptionMetered
@Path("/path")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response demoSetCookie()
{
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("testNameCookie", "testValueCookie");
    NewCookie cookies = new NewCookie(cookie);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).entity(view).cookie(cookies)
                    .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd add another option to the list - as I think it's *slightly* cleaner...

```
@GET
@ExceptionMetered
@Path("/path")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response demoSetCookie(@Context HttpServletResponse response)
{
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookiemonster", "wannacookie");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    return new MyViewResource();
}
```